# The angle between 2 vectors

Tags: vectors

Here are 2 vectors:

**u** = 4i - 2j + 4k

**v** = 3i - 6j - 2k

I'm sure finding the angle is something along the lines of:

**u.v** = (4 * 3) + (2 * 6) + (4 * 2) = 32

However I'm very sure I have missed a step or maybe even done this wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: you computed a dot product, not an angle.

Comment: Based on this question and your previous post, it seems to me that you may want to consult a textbook for definitions. To find an angle you need a formula where you can solve for theta.

Comment: Your dot product is also wrong, take care of the $\pm $ signs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by definition of dot product,$$\vec a.\vec b=|\vec a||\vec b|\cos \theta$$
Where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec a$ and $\vec b$.

$$\implies \cos \theta = \frac{\vec a.\vec b}{|\vec a||\vec b|}$$
In your example,
$$\vec a.\vec b=16$$ and 
$$|\vec a||\vec b|=42$$
So,
$$\cos\theta =\frac{8}{21}$$
$$\implies \theta = \arccos\frac{8}{21}$$